# Node.js server with web browser cors error

Tags: node.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
  next();
});

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin,Content-Type, Authorization, x-id, Content-Length, X-Requested-With");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
    next();
});

app.get('/', (request, response) => {
  response.send('Hello from Express!')
  console.log("hi");
})

app.use('/', (request, response) => {
  response.send('Hello from Express!')
  console.log("hi");
})

app.listen(port, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.log('something bad happened', err)
  }

  console.log(`server is listening on ${port}`)
})
```

Here is my node.js server code

When connecting with a webpage, I receive from f12 network tab

https://localhost:3000 http connect 200(connection established)

yet, my node.js app doesn't output anything. Any suggestions?

Note, I used fiddler and received this response

> HTTPS handshake to localhost (for #125) failed. System.IO.IOException The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your question you are using `https` in your request. Unless you've configured SSL elsewhere, like behind nginx, for example, this won't work. There is nothing in your application dealing with a secure connection. Change it to `http` and it should work.

Comment: The website is a https, changing the request to deal with http gives me a "HTTPS security is compromised by http://localhost:3000" error, any more thoughts?

Comment: Yeah. If the website is https you need to go through the process of setting up a certificate on your machine. https://aghassi.github.io/ssl-using-express-4/ Here is an example of how to set that up.